# Вылет программы C++(Segmentation fault)

Tags: c++

После появления запроса на ввод чисел программа вылет с такой ошибкой:
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

long double raf(int a , ...)
{
    int *p = &a;
    int b = 0;
    for(; a != 0; a++)
    {
        b+= *(++p);
    }
    int c = b/a;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Midle count of numbers 5,3,9,1,7: " << endl;
    raf(5,5,3,9,1,7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в отладчике вы уже смотрели, где именно вылетает?

Comment: Вы почему-то считаете, что адрес следующего аргумента можно получить из адреса предыдущего при помощи инкремента. Стандарт этого не гарантирует.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов К сожалению компилю на ubuntu с помощью g++ так что возможности глянуть неть

Comment: @TRIGUN117: ну так освойте отладчик. Или перейдите на Windows/Visual Studio, если не можете освоить gdb.

Comment: Боюсь, что даже в машине с передачей аргументов в стеке с соглашением, что первый аргумент задает количество следующих за ним, вот такой `for(; a != 0; a++)
    {
        b+= *(++p);
    }` (для небольшого положительного `a`) явно не соответствует задуманному. (наверное, для такой машины надо было бы не увеличивать, а уменьшать `a`) / (Но в любом случае это не переносимый метод и так писать не стоит. Используйте совет про `va_list` из ответа)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если уж хочется использовать **нестандартный** метод, то все равно делать это нужно правильно:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long double raf(int a , ...)
{
    int *p = &a;
    int cnt = a;
    int b = 0;
    for(; cnt != 0; --cnt)
    {
        b+= *(++p);
    }
    return ((long double)b)/a;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Midle count of numbers 5,3,9,1,7: " << endl;
    cout << raf(5,5,3,9,1,7) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Посмотрите у себя - цикл ставите бесконечный (пока *растущее* `a` не станет нулем, потом делите на него - нулевое... Делите целочисленно, а надеетесь получить  `long double`... Наконец, просто не выводите полученный результат. Об английском языке промолчу :)

Стандартное же решение такое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

long double raf(int a , ...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p,a);
    int cnt = a;
    int b = 0;
    for(; cnt != 0; --cnt)
    {
        b+= va_arg(p,int);
    }
    va_end(p);
    return ((long double)b)/a;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Midle count of numbers 5,3,9,1,7: " << endl;
    cout << raf(5,5,3,9,1,7) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Доступ к variadic аргументам функций (параметры `...`) в С и С++ делается только через `va_list` и макросы `va_start/va_arg/va_end`. Других способов не существует.

Поэтому ни о каком `int *p = &a;` и прочей вашей "адресной арифметике" не может быть и речи. Это какая-то белиберда, непонятно откуда вами выкопанная. Неудивительно, что дело заканчивается Segmentation fault.

Comment: Как ни смешно (и грустно) но Гугл выкидывает массу ссылок, в которых начинают действовать вот так, как *пытается* ТС...